# Ruby on rails redirect_to to an external url call the method twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a view that call a simple method of controller

```
<p><%= link_to "Log In external app", login_with_external_app_path %></p>
```

The controller does :

```
  def login_with_external_app
    params = {secret_key: ENV['SECRET_APP_KEY'], scope: 'x:y' }
    uri = URI('https://an_app.com/login/oauth/authorize')
    uri.query = params.to_query
    redirect_to(uri.to_s)
  end
```

The method login_with_external_app is called twice. The first one is when I click on the button of my view, after clicking the piece of code is executed properly and it not redirects to the uri properly (the console shows me that the application found the URL ), after that the method is called again and it redirects fine.

The console logs:

> Started GET "/login_with_external_app" for ::1 at 2016-12-03 11:23:11
>   -0300 Processing by SessionsController#login_with_external_app as HTML
>
> Redirected to
>   https://an_app.com/login/oauth/authorize?secret_key=123456&scope=x%3y
>   Completed 302 Found in 2824ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> Started GET "/login_with_external_app" for ::1 at 2016-12-03 11:23:15
>   -0300 Processing by SessionsController#login_with_external_app as HTML

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can divulge more information but from this, it seems your method is being called twice. You didn't by any chance put that method in a before_action, did you?

Comment: I didn't put the method in a callback method.

Comment: Try using binding.pry in that method. Use the `next` keyword so you can know the exact way the code is being run

Comment: I did it, the problem seems to be in the gem I debugged the gem and it make the call twice.

Comment: Nice find. You can contact the author of the gem or contribute to it if it is open source

Comment: @nachoc could be great if you explained what was the problem exactly, name of the gem,  and how did you solve it. What was the name of the gem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found that if I use a post link instead it solved the problem. So in the above case use:

```
<p><%= link_to "Log In external app", login_with_external_app_path, method: :post %></p>
```

Then remember to change the routes from get to post as well.